# When to use `UIControl` instead of `UIView` for implementing custom components in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to implement a component like this:

[image]

Users can select colors, and selected color indicated by a checkmark.
The question is, for this kind of components, do I have to use `UIControl`, or `UIView`? which one is more reasonable? and why?

```swift
class MyComponent: UIControl {
  //...
}
```

or

```swift
class MyComponent: UIView {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`UIControl` actually inherits from `UIView`, with specific added functionality. Choosing whether to subclass a `UIControl` comes down to whether you need the specific extra functionality it provides.
Some of the default functionality `UIControl` provides are:

- Support for target-action mechanism, e.g. calling:
  `myControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunc), for: .valueChanged)`
- `state`, `isEnabled`, `isSelected` and more properties that are associated with `UIControl`s.
- Default Interface builder support.
- Accessibility purposes

If you need or want to adopt some of the above functionality and behaviors, `UIControl` can be a good way to go. Otherwise, if you don't need most of the functionality, perhaps creating a custom `UIView` can be simpler with less to deal with by default.
Also, mind that the target-action mechanism works with Objective-C based selectors for callbacks, which is considered kind of old nowadays and very un-swifty, but obviously still used by `UIKit`'s buttons, sliders, text fields and basically all other base UI elements.

You can read more about `UIControl` in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) to understand the functionality it provides.